# Get fix number of records by grouping of date according to registered date of the user

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am stuck with a query, and not sure how can we achieve this -

I have one user table and another is user_transactions table. I need to get the data from transaction table according to date of user created. Interesting thing is need to get only 10 or less records always.

**for example today is 30 Aug 2020,and User registered on 21 Aug 2020, then the result will be -**

```
21 Aug 2020 : 1050
22 Aug 2020 : 100
...
..
30 Aug 2020 : 1000
```

It mean it will show the date from 21 August - 30 August with single date and total transactions on that date.

**But now If the user is registered on 01 August 2020, then total 30 days are completed, but still I need 10 records and the result will be --**

```
01 Aug 2020 - 03 Aug 2020 - 5000
04 Aug 2020 - 06 Aug 2020 - 50000
...
...
28 Aug 2020 - 30 Aug 2020 - 8000
```

It means total 10 records returns with total transactions of 3 - 3 days. If that from 1 year then sum of each 36 days transactions will be returns in total 10 rows.

Please help me  for this query.

here is my table structure ----

```
**users table ---
id | name | email | created_at

transactions table ----

id | user_id | amount | created_at**
```

Now I need to get data based on the user_id according to that user created_at and sum of amount based on the transactions created_at date

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not understand the task. You need help with correct SQL or you need to post-process your results in PHP?

Comment: @Anton I need help to create the sql query to get the result set to achieve the target.. its not a php specific..

Comment: In that case we need your table structure (examples?) and SQL that you have tried.

Comment: @Anton Please check i updated the table structures..

Comment: @Anton I tried the simple group by date for that transaction and sum of amount, but I am confused how I will apply the group by according to the group of dates like 1-3 aug and so on which can be dynamic i.e. 2 days, 5 days, 35 days

Comment: Where is types in table structure? :) what type is for `created_at` field?

Comment: Do you know how many days you will request *before* executing SQL? For example if you need 01-30 Aug, so the number of days `30` must be known before SQL. Is it ok?

Comment: Sorry for late response @Anton. the records will be 10 always and grouping will be done according to number of days. like 1-30 aug will return the total of 3 days of transactions. like 1-3 aug -> 5000 if total range is 100 days from date created then total 10 rows will be returned sum of 10 days transactions and total will be 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are not answering, I will make a guess...

So here is a table:

```sql
create table transactions(
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id int,
  amount int,
  created_at timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The table test data (do not run it in code snippet - this is just to make expandable box):

```js
insert into transactions (user_id, amount, created_at) values
  (1, 1050, '2020-08-15'),
  (1, 150, '2020-08-15 10:00:00'),
  (1, 1050, '2020-08-16'),
  (1, 150, '2020-08-16 10:00:00'),
  (1, 1050, '2020-08-17'),
  (1, 150, '2020-08-17 10:00:00'),
  (1, 1050, '2020-08-18'),
  (1, 150, '2020-08-18 10:00:00'),
  (1, 1050, '2020-08-19'),
  (1, 150, '2020-08-19 10:00:00'),
  (1, 1050, '2020-08-20'),
  (1, 150, '2020-08-20 10:00:00'),
  (1, 1050, '2020-08-21'),
  (1, 150, '2020-08-21 10:00:00'),
  (1, 500, '2020-08-22'),
  (1, 200, '2020-08-22 12:00:00'),
  (1, 1000, '2020-08-23'),
  (1, 100, '2020-08-23 01:01:01'),
  (1, 50, '2020-08-24'),
  (1, 50, '2020-08-24 14:00:00'),
  (1, 150, '2020-08-25'),
  (1, 350, '2020-08-25 13:13:13'),
  (1, 250, '2020-08-26'),
  (1, 250, '2020-08-26 14:14:24'),
  (1, 450, '2020-08-27'),
  (1, 40, '2020-08-27 11:11:11'),
  (1, 300, '2020-08-28'),
  (1, 300, '2020-08-28 12:12:12'),
  (1, 1150, '2020-08-29'),
  (1, 115, '2020-08-29 12:12:12'),
  (1, 1250, '2020-08-30')
  ;
```

The idea is to make 2 queries:

- one `T1` will add row numbers to grouping and count total number of days
- second will group days by date intervals.

I've used [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9cda3/3) to play with MySQL, so I can't create a) temporary tables, b) `with` selects, so I created a "temporary" table `T1`:

```sql
create table T1 (d timestamp, amount int, rowidx int);
  
set @row_num = 0;
  
insert into T1
  select DATE(created_at) as d, sum(amount) as amount, @row_num := @row_num + 1 as rowidx
  from transactions
  where user_id = 1
  group by DATE(created_at);
```

Now we know total number of days and can make final grouping:

```sql
select count(*) from T1 into @total;

select min(d) as min_date, max(d) as max_date, sum(amount) as amount
from T1
group by CEIL(rowidx / @total * 10)
```

Explanation: if we divide row index by the total number of rows (`rowidx / @total`), we will have a number from 0 (exclusive) to 1 (inclusive). If then we will multiply it by 10 (or other number - depends on how many resulting lines do we need) rounding up, then we will have number from 1 (inclusive) to 10 (inclusive). So we use `CEIL(rowidx / @total * 10)` as grouping value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check it out. So the second query will return only 10 records always. right? even the the date range is 10 days, 1 month or 1 year..

Comment: @PHPGeek good that you asked. I found one small bug in my example and fixed it. Besides that I've added some explanation.

Comment: Thanks Anton. Data getting correct, but the group of min_date and total_count is coming wrong..

Comment: @PHPGeek can you explain what you mean by `min_date and total_count is wrong`? Maybe we can make something about it.